# Wordpress if (is_page) translation on certain page

Tags: php, functions, wp-admin, translation

Hy there i have the following code for custom translations there are missing.

```
function translate_text( $translated ) {
$translated = str_ireplace( 'All Ratings',  'Alle Bewertug',  $translated );
$translated = str_ireplace( 'No Ratings',  'keine Bewertug',  $translated );
$translated = str_ireplace( 'Ratings',  'Bewertug',  $translated );
  return $translated;
}

add_filter( 'gettext',  'translate_text' );
add_filter( 'ngettext',  'translate_text' );
```

it works fine, but on every Wordpress Pages. I would like this code to only be used on certain pages...
Page name is "wprecipemaker"
For example: wp-admin/admin.php?page=wprecipemaker#/

I try a lot with `if (is_page)` but unfortunately without success. Does anyone have any ideas? That would help me a lot.

Comment: I suppose you put the condition test inside translate_text() function, right? If you want to have a small trial by each step. You can check the post ID first such as global $post; $post->ID === ... or get_the_ID(). And if ID is too specific, you may then try $post->post_name. I think this direction could help.